# NextJS 14 Server Action formData getting truncated at 1MB. bodySizeLimit not working

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I have a NextJS 14 app (app routing) with a client form that is submitting some Base64 data to a server action. Before the server action is called, I can verify that the FormData is the right size. When I call the server action, I see that my JSON is getting truncated to 1024kb.

From my "use client" based form:

```
          const imageBase64 = await convertFileToBase64(imageFile);
          console.log(
            `Form Payload size: ${new Blob([imageBase64 ?? ""]).size / 1024} KB`
          );
          data.append("imageBase64", imageBase64);
        }

        const chat = await createChat(data, responseHistory);
```

The console shows the correct size

Then in the "use server" createChat function:

```
const imageBase64 = formData.get("imageBase64") as string | null;
  console.log(
    `Action Payload size: ${new Blob([imageBase64 ?? ""]).size / 1024} KB`
  );
```

This is always 1024kb.

I thought that obviously it is the 1MB default server action limit, so I changed my next.config.js as recommended in the docs:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    serverActions: {
      bodySizeLimit: "10mb",
    },
  },
};
```

But this does not fix the issue. The data always gets truncated to 1024kb when it reaches the server action function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with the Next.js action handler and busboy.

Here is the original issue:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/59277#issuecomment-1867445275

There is a pull request that resolves the issue...waiting to be merged into canary:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/61462